# Erro ao plotar gráfico com o ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

Suponha um dataset em que conste o ano, seguido da quantidade de livros publicados por um autor:

```
df<-tibble(
  ano = c(2007, 2008, 2017, 2018),
  n = c(1, 2, 2, 1)
)

df

# A tibble: 4 x 2
    ano     n
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2007     1
2  2008     2
3  2017     2
4  2018     1
```

Se eu tento criar um gráfico com:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ano, n))+
  geom_line()
```

...eu obtenho o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha interpretação à respeito do gráfico gerado (me corrijam se eu estiver errado, por favor), é que, segundo o gráfico, foi publicado 1 livro em 2007, 2 livros em 2008, e 2 livros **a cada ano** entre 2008 e 2017 e, novamente, 1 livro em 2018.

A questão é que, na verdade, entre 2008 e 2017 não há nenhum registro.

Imaginei que, pelo fato de ter colocado o ano simplesmente como um número (ou seja, sem tê-lo classificado como ano), tivesse causado esse equívoco.

Então, converti a coluna "ano" em anos (de fato) com a expectativa de resolver a questão. Usei a função `ymd()` do lubridate e salvei em um novo dataset chamado "df2":

```
df2<-df %>% 
  mutate(ano = ymd(paste0(ano, "01", "01")))

df2

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  ano            n
  <date>     <dbl>
1 2007-01-01     1
2 2008-01-01     2
3 2017-01-01     2
4 2018-01-01     1
```

E plotei o gráfico:

```
df2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ano, n))+
  geom_line()+
  theme_bw()
```

No entanto, como resultado, tive exatamente o mesmo gráfico de antes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

... não sei, a minha expectativa é que o gráfico correto seria uma linha (subindo) que vai de x=2007, y=1 até x=2008, y=2 -- depois outra linha (descendo) que vai de x=2017, y=2 até x=2018, y=1. Em outras palavras, no meu entender não deveria haver essa linha (reta) ligando 2008 a 2018 em y=2.

Onde está meu erro?

Comment: boa noite! Se não existe registro que ligue o valor a data, esse comportamento não deve acontecer... uma forma de plotar é converter em factor mas mesmo assim não vai ter esse decaimento que você espera. Abraço!

Comment: O `geom_line` liga os pontos de acordo com o eixo x. É um comportamento comum de bibliotecas gráficas em R/Python que o programa não tem como saber a frequência das observações e se ligar elas é relevante ou não. O ideal é completar os dados do eixo x e dar a eles o valor de 0 ou NA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um exemplo criando a sequencia de datas com o n igual a zero

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <-data.frame(
  ano = c(2007, 2008, 2017, 2018),
  n = c(1, 2, 2, 1)
)

anos <- data.frame(ano = 2007:2018)

left_join(anos, df, by = 'ano') %>%  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  ggplot( aes(factor(ano),factor(n), group = 1) )+
    geom_line()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução é usar a função `tidyr::complete`.

```
df %>% 
  complete(ano = 2007:2018, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(ano, n))+
  geom_line()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]